# How to design :: Linear Algebra Routines for a matrix

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, matrix

In C++ , for education purposes , I am building a linear algebra package.
My question is how can a design a good interface for the user.

I have a matrix class which can be created as

```
matrix<int> A (3,3)
```

This class deals with the data that is stored in the matrix, how to traverse through them , get a particular element, printing the matrix etc...

I have another class Linear Algebra , which does the mathematical computations on the matrix. So it will work like this

```
LA<int> B ;

// I have a method in LA , which gives the determinant. 

matrix<int> C = B.determinant(A);

// Just doesn't look good to me, I want to be able to do this 

matrix<int> C = determinant(A); // This seems more natural 

// Is there any way to eliminate the need to create an LA object ?
```

One way would be to define determinant within A and call A.determinant(). But this does not give me modularity.

So how can I do this ?

Additionally

- Do you know some way to cut down on the user having to type matrix< int>. Can I use a typedef ?
- if you were using this class , would you prefer determinant() or some short form of determinant. Using the short form would mean less typing, but that would make the code less understandable too. How do I make this trade off.
- I plan on looking at how other Linear Algebra classes like bltiz do this. But I am afraid it would be too high level for me to understand the technique they use. Would you make any suggestions (books , website etc.) where I can learn about design patterns , and about how to write huge code without it breaking down.
- Thank you

Comment: Why can't you make determinate a free function? I.e define it within a namespace

Comment: @Kam okay , so instead of using a class I could define a namespace with these functions in them. yes that will work , but is there some way to do it in the OO way ? A main aim of mine in doing this , is to understand OO better too.

Comment: OO means that things are encapsulated within an object. You can have a utility namespace, then locally you can use typedef UTILITY::determinant determinant; then use determinant(A)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a utility namespace:

```
namespace UTILITY {
// define determinant here
}
```

Then locally you can use:

```
typedef UTILITY::determinant determinant;
```

then use:

```
determinant(A);
```

Comment: is there any C++ standard as to where I should put this in ? in a .h or a .cpp file ? thanks

Comment: You can split declarations in header file and the definition in cpp files